# How to add a default value of an EF Core shadow property to existing entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm a bit stuck trying to add a `shadow propery` to my existing entities. I add shadow property in `OnModelCreating`. The property is configured like this:

```
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.Property<Guid>("TenantId")
            .HasDefaultValue(CommonConstants.DefaultTenantId);

        base.Configure(builder);
    }
```

Then I run `add-migration` and get this error:

> The seed entity for entity type `SomeEntity` cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property `TenantId`.

Although the value has been provided as you see above.

My expectation was that migration would determine the changes, add new `column` `TenantId` and populate existing entries in the database with the default value.

Any ideas how to make it work?

UPD: A have already read [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13462) issue, which confirms my assumption that migration should pick up the default value.

Comment: This will add default value for new records. To update your existing records you need write sql command to update the records. Add in your migration modelBuilder.Sql(“your sql query something like update tableName set TalantedId = ...”). Also make sure to add the sql after column is created.

Comment: @Kos Thanks for suggestion, but I was unable to find the `Sql()` method on `modelBuilder.` Are you using some third party package?

Comment: My bad... it is in the `migrationBuilder` in the generated migration.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either, because `migrationBuilder` is only available *inside* migration, but the error is thrown during the process of adding a migration